# Multiple Entity Managers with Test ENV

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, php-8.1, symfony6

I am working with multiple Entity Managers and Connections in both ***DEV*** and ***PROD*** environements without any problem.

In ***TEST*** environement I tried to add another connection inside `doctrine.yaml` file like this:

[image]

But only the database related to default connection is created with command `symfony console --env=test doctrine:database:create` (I need both of them),

Should I follow the same configuration I did before with ***DEV*** environment to configure two entity managers or can I directly add two `dbname_suffix` under test bloc ?

Comment: sure it is in env-files? (`.env.local` and/or `.env.test` )
try to `composer dump-env test` to make all env-vars in `.env.local.php`

Comment: Yes both Database URI are in env-files.
I just need both database created with command `symfony console --env=test doctrine:database:create`, in my case the `default` one only was added

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--connection` attribute like:

`symfony console --env=test doctrine:database:create --connection=microservice`